# Error when moving solr folder between servers

Tags: windows, solr

After some questions I've decided to edit the question:

Let me try to explain what happened. I had a solr configured with 200M index and was working fine. It was on c:\solr on server A. I had to move this content to another server, because server A will not exist anymore. Basically I've copied all the content to the new server, but this time on E: And my solr only display "loading". I believe that I need to set a variable or a parameter in a xml file with this change: "root drive is e: and not c:" but I don't know where.

Is there any configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: I think it will be easier for people to help you if you share some more detail - what content/folder did you copy, was Solr already installed in the new server, where did you place it on the new server, relevant sections of your solrconfig.xml, Solr version, java version.

Comment: If this is in the context of an upgrade, there are many reasons this might not work. If not, are you zipping the entire data dir? transaction log and all?

Comment: I've copied all solr content folder. Previously was on c: and now it's e:. I need to switch this. Where is {solr.data.index}  defined?

Comment: Have a look in your solr.xml, if you still have one, and check if a `<property name="dataDir" value="xxx">` is defined. This is described in [the Solr Wiki Entry about the solr.xml](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%20%28supported%20through%204.x%29).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to perform this by hand? Solr has build in mechanisms to move its' index between servers. Have a look at these topics

- [Index Replication](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication)
- [Backing Up](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Backing+Up)

In the reference is written about index replication

> Index Replication distributes complete copies of a master index to one or more slave servers. The master server continues to manage updates to the index. All querying is handled by the slaves. This division of labor enables Solr to scale to provide adequate responsiveness to queries against large search volumes.

You probably will not need the query behaviour of master and slave. But the distribution of indexes sound very like the thing you are trying to do.

Comment: It's not a master slave relationship. I really need to move all that content. Where {solr.data.index} variable is defined ?

Comment: Well, as I said, you may not need that separation of query labour. But a slave receives a full and functional copy of the master index.

Comment: Let me try to explain what happened. I had a solr configured with 200M index and was working fine. It was on c:\solr on server A. I had to move this content to another server, because server A will not exist anymore. Basically I've copied all the content to the new server, but this time on E: And my solr only display "loading". I believe that I need to set a variable or a parameter in a xml file with this change: "root drive is e: and not c:" but I don't know where.

Comment: Ok, so the old server is gone now and you have some sort of "last resort"-copy and you need to get that going, right? Are both servers equals in terms of operation system?

Comment: Yes, they're. The only difference: now i'm using e: instead of c: